# Bootstrap checkbox input align vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap version 2.3.2, I have a form layout like the below image and since the checkbox has an inline label, there is an aligning issue.

[image]

Adding margin to `input[type="checkbox"]` only gives margin to the checkbox, not the inline label. How do I make it so the checkbox and its label vertically align to the text fields next to it?

Here is the 
[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/ifeJURO/1/edit) if you are interested.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your **HTML** add a class that will handle the checkbox margin:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
      <label>label 1</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      <label>label 2</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="span3 checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" />test description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in your **CSS**:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
 // i just remove this part..
}
.checkbox {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
```

Don't put the margin on the checkbox, but on the parent div.
Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/EYiTar/1/edit?html,css,output).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 9):

Try to always use something like this:

```
<div class="span3">
    <label for="checkbox" class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox">test description
    </label>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/itAdAWA/1/edit

Comment: And I just noticed, you are using Bootstrap, but none of the actual classes you should be using to set up your form... Work on that... `.control-group`, `.control-label`, etc...

Comment: I had label, input[type="checkbox"] and span element in one line. Adding class="checkbox" to the input and class="form-inline" to the parent div did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting a `<label>` before the checkbox like this? ..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span3">
        <label>label 1</label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <label>label 2</label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <label>test</label>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Bootply: http://bootply.com/86998

Comment: Out of the answers given your answer and Giovanni's above are the only 2 that truely make bootstrap since.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this exact problem in bootstrap 3, by simply limiting the height of inline checkboxes to 12 pixels. They are by default 40px, I don't know why !

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
        <span>My correctly aligned check-box</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

add this in your css file (I personally have a css file named bootstrap-custom.css):

```
/*
Checkboxes in inline forms are misaligned because for an unknow reason they inherit a height of 40px !
This selector limit the height of inline checkboxes to 12px which is the perfect value to align them to
the other widgets in an inline form.
*/
.radio-inline, .checkbox-inline {
    max-height: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal solution but change your code to ...

```
<div class="span5">
    <input type="checkbox">test description</input>
  </div>
```

and set the margin-top on that.  I will result as you want - better.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap v5+

[image: Desktop view]

[image: Mobile view]

```
<!-- mt-md-4 pt-md-3 this apply margin and padding only for desktop -->

<div class="col-md-3 mb-3 md-mt-4 md-pt-3">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                Default checkbox
              </label>
        </div>
```